# How to exclude certain resources from the maven war plugin war file?

Tags: maven, war

We've been using `war:exploded` for a while now and I'm trying to do away with it.  I've added the following to my pom:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
</resource>
```

This copies files such as the in `src/main/webapp/keystore` into `target/classes/keystore` so my local UI launcher works and sees everything.  Score!

However, by adding to the resources list, this means that the same files also show up in the `war` file as `keystore` (correct) *and* `WEB-INF/classes/keystore` (wrong).  It also means there there is a `WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF` directory (blah).  I'm trying to exclude the resource files from `src/main/webapp` resource since `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` is already a resource.

I'm trying not to specifically exclude `keystore` and other files since we add/delete from that list semi-often.  I've tried to add the following (and a number of other variants) to the war plugin configuration without results:

```
<webResources>
   <resource>
      <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
      <excludes>
         <exclude>**</exclude>
      </excludes>
   </resource>
</webResources>
```

I've also read a number of other SO questions and I've spent at least an hour reading docs on from the [maven war plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) and tried other configs without success.

Any idea what magic I need to do here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about moving the keystore directory into /src/main/resources instead of having it in /src/main/webapp?  Then the maven-resources-plugin will handle the copy into target/classes/keystore.

Comment: `keystore` is a file @user944849.  I could do that but I think that would break the war in other ways.  The webapp layout is textbook from a war plugin perspective: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

Comment: I think I must be missing something.  The question says the keystore file should be at the top level of the war (keystore) not in the war's typical location (WEB-INF/classes/keystore).  Thus, you are looking to do something a little different than the textbook war plugin method.  The way to do what you're asking for in Maven is to put the file in /src/main/resources.

Comment: So if you are talking about wars @user944849, then typically the web resources are put in src/main/webapp.  That's where the keystore file is located and it is copied (appropriately) into the root of the war classpath.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>**/keystore</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Also See**

- [Including and Excluding Files From the WAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm trying to "not specifically exclude keystore and other files" like the post states.  Any way to exclude a particular overlapping resource directory?

Comment: just replace `**/keystore` with your desired pattern

Comment: The pattern can just be a CSV in case you still find this confusing.  I have a simple example here: http://www.codescream.com/ContentDisplay?targetContent=ExcludeFilesFromMavenWarDeployment that just shows it with a specific properties file and a logging config file. I found the more-intense expression in the Maven doc a little confusing as well the first time around.

Answer (score 5):

warSourceExcludes  worked for me. for example.To exclude js folder and scss folder from my war i tried...

```
 <configuration>
   <warSourceExcludes>js/*.*,scss/*.*</warSourceExcludes>      
   <webResources>
     <resource>
     <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
     <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>WEB-INF/web.xml</include>
        </includes>
     </resource>
   </webResources>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, by adding to the resources list, this means that the same files also show up in the war file as `keystore` (correct) and `WEB-INF/classes/keystore` (wrong).

I was *not* able to get the war-plugin to properly exclude the `webapp` directory while at the same time allowing the `webapp/WEB-INF` directory.  Instead of adding the following to the pom:

```
<!-- bad idea, this didn't work -->
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
</resource>
```

I switched to using the resources-plugin to be able to copy certain resources over during the `validate` phase:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/webapp</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I initially copied the `webapp` directory into `target/classes` but that also seemed to make it into the resulting war file which was what I was trying to avoid.  I have the feeling that I could have solved this if necessary.

Instead I decided to copy the `webapp` files into the `target/webapp` directory and change my program to look for the resources there:

```
String RESOURCE_BASE = "target/webapp";
System.setProperty("server.jetty.webapp.resourceBase", RESOURCE_BASE + "/");
System.setProperty("server.jetty.ssl.keystore", RESOURCE_BASE + "/keystore");
System.setProperty("server.jetty.ssl.truststore", RESOURCE_BASE + "/keystore");
...
```

This seems to be working well.  Testing locally now works (without war-exploded!!) and the files are not doubly included in the resulting war file.  In addition, I added a symlink at runtime from `target/webapp/views/cms` to point to our CMS hierarchy which is in another project.