# How to exclude certain file extensions from the build

Tags: maven

I want to exclude files with certain file extensions e.g. .swp from being included in the build, how can I do this? So if a .swp file is in the source folder, it should not be copied over to the build

Comment: It depends. What are you building? Typically, your build plugin will have some configuration to enable excluding. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/19170720/112934